# Console unresponsive following a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to reorganize some data. Here is a description of the files:

```
60 csv files
40 columns
250 rows
```

What I am trying to do is remove useless columns so it is more readable. I choose to do this with a loop. My code:

```
file.number <- paste0(rep(c(1:30), each = 2), rep(c('a','b')), '.csv') # lists file names (works fine)

d1 <-setNames(lapply(file.number, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE),paste(file.number)) # imports data into r (works fine)
i = 1
while (i <= length(file.number)){
  index <- i # indexs 
  nam <- paste0("d2",i) # creates new file name (same problem with this line of code removed)
  d2 <- subset(d1[[index]], select = c('column.1','column.2','column.2')) # If i run this line of code outside the loop by just indexing a specific file it runs fine, it just doesn't work in the loop 
  assign(nam, d2) # creates a new file name (I run into the same problem with this line of code removed
}
```

So when I run this loop, the R console becomes unresponsive. I've run loops pretty similar to this before without a problem. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your loop control `while (i <= length(file.number))` to `for (i in 1:length(file.number))`. This will increment `i` as the loop goes. Otherwise put an `i <- i + 1` inside the `while` loop.

A simple debugging tip: you can insert an `print(i)` in your loop next time, and run it. If the program does work, you will see `i` always increasing; otherwise you know there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is always 1, so your `while` loop continues forever.